# How can I set BackgroundColor on Kotlin for button?

Tags: android, kotlin, button, android-button

[image: Here's a imagen of my situation]

I had been searching how to change color for the background of a button and I the closest I got for that was using

`view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white))`

But when I do that the button doesn't turn white, it turns purple? That's like the default color for buttons, and I really don't know what to do.

Thank you for your help and I'm sorry if I don't reply :( I can't understand how to use this page very well

Answer (score 1):

Use the **`setBackgroundTintList`** instead of the `setBackgroundColor`.

Something like:

```
button.backgroundTintList = ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this,R.color.xxxx);
```

You can use a simple color:

```
<color name="red600">#e53935</color>
```

or better a selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_enabled="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.12" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface"/>
</selector>
```

The default background color is defined by the **`colorPrimary`** attribute in your theme.

Comment: Hello thank you for answering :) What do you mean with button_selector ? thank you!

Comment: You can use a simple color or a selector. Check https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource

Comment: @MeowYOU I've updated the answer with an example

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change the color on runtime with the help of these

// In Java    btn.setBackgroundColor(btn.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.red));

In kotlin

```
btn.setBackgroundColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
```

or

```
btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

and with the help of RGB : 0xAARRGGBB

```
btn.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFF0000);
```

Comment: Hello thank you for answering :) But I tried that and I think that those lines are for java but not for kotlin :( Or am I wrong? I'm still learning

Comment: now I mention to you how you can change the color in kotlin.